# Discord.js bot: How can I check if the person who pings has certain role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I was trying to create a warning about pinging staff, my current code is:

```
const roleId = "761874957705674762";

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(roleId)) {
        await message.delete();
        message.reply(`dont ping staff!`);
        message.delete(5000);
    };
});
```

I don't get any errors, but I also don't get the desired respond "don't ping staff"

Comment: It should work fine. The role ID must be wrong then. Also after replying `don't ping staff`, `message.delete()` would not work. You need to use `.then()` to delete the sent message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check a user for roles by the role ID:

```
// assuming role.id is an actual ID of a valid role:
if(message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
  console.log(`Yay, the author of the message has the role!`);
} else {
  console.log(`Nope, noppers, nadda.`);
}
```

And if you want to check if he has one of multiple roles, you can do this:

```
// Check if they have one of many roles
if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>["Dev", "Mod", "Server Staff", "Proficient"].includes(r.name)) ) {
  // has one of the roles
} else {
  // has none of the roles
}
```